# I accidentally booked a non-refundable stay in the wrong location. Can I get money back?

Tags: refunds, accommodation-search-engines

I booked a last minute non-refundable stay on priceline.com but I've accidentally booked it in the wrong state. I immediately let priceline.com know and I tried to get a hold of the hotel but no answer.

I had gotten a message from priceline.com saying that they would work on getting my refund because they could see the it was in completely different state.  I waited over a week,but they have now told me that the hotel themselves wouldn't release the refund so they can't refund me the money.

Is there any way for me to get money or credit (for that hotel) back from this?

Comment: It all depends on the policy of the hotel. Booking.com are only acting as an intermediary here. It’s probably a lot easier if the hotel is part of a chain and you rebook in a different hotel of the same group, but even then they probably have no obligation to refund a non-refundable booking.

Comment: And I know that some pre-booked Holiday Inn bookings in UK cannot be re-booked with another local HI hotel even in the same area, when the customer mistakenly booked in the wrong town.

Comment: Instead of trying to get a straight up refund from that hotel, the fact that you booked the wrong state suggests they are a chain, so maybe try and call the chain themselves about moving the booking to the correct location.

Comment: @WeatherVane perhaps because Holiday Inn is largely a franchise operation, more so than many of their rivals

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question "is this fair?", I say, yes.

You booked a last-minute, non-refundable room. Effectively, robbing the hotel from an opportunity to sell the room to someone else.

If you make mistakes, customer care of Booking.com tries to plead your case with the hotel, and often hotels are willing to waive the cancellation fee (I've made mistakes, and customer care of Booking.com has always been able to get the cancellation fee waived for me). But due to COVID, hotels are going through a rough time. They may be far less lenient than they were in the past.

Having said that, look closely how the prices is broken down. You should not have to pay any city tax (that is, European style city tax, also called tourist tax (US city tax is more like VAT in Europe)). If there are any cleaning or similar fees included in the price, you have a strong case you don't have to pay those.